# STTweetLabel intro UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, tableview, cell

I used this https://github.com/SebastienThiebaud/STTweetLabel

But I'm trying to add it to UITableViewCell as below

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (!cell) {

cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

}

STTweetLabel *_tweetLabel = [[STTweetLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0, 60.0, 280.0, 230.0)];
[_tweetLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:17.0]];
[_tweetLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
STLinkCallbackBlock callbackBlock = ^(STLinkActionType actionType, NSString *link) {

    SString *displayString = NULL;

    switch (actionType) {

        case STLinkActionTypeAccount:
            displayString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Twitter account:\n%@", link];
            break;

        case STLinkActionTypeHashtag:
            displayString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Twitter hashtag:\n%@", link];
            break;

        case STLinkActionTypeWebsite:
            displayString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Website:\n%@", link];
            break;
    }

    NSLog(@"%@",displayString);

    };

    [_tweetLabel setCallbackBlock:callbackBlock];
    [_tweetLabel setText:@"http://www.google.com"];
    [cell addSubview:_tweetLabel];

    return cell;

}
```

But the error is:

```
-[__NSArrayM set]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x750b160
2013-04-03 15:36:36.425 Shahona Fashion[18426:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM set]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x750b160'
```

So my question is, is it possible to add intro tableView cell, or there is something way to detech urls in that way ?

Thanks in advance ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want the first cell of your table to be different from the rest?

You could try a simple if statement.

```
if (indexPath.row == 0)
{
    //set up as "intro cell"
} else {
    //set up the rest of your cells
}
```

Also, it doesn't look like your error is related to the code on your table. Look toward any arrays in your app.

Comment: No not this is my problem, i'm just asking about use STTweetLabel into cell

Comment: Apologies. I misunderstood the question. You might be better off creating a custom cell class and implementing your STTweetLabel there. But before you can do any of that you have to get rid of your error which, as I said, is related to an array somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is related to STTweetLabel. It's a bug fixed in STTweetLabel 3.0.